# How to avoid flicker when a page first loads due to CSS styles changing via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I' having a little trouble between load order of my CSS and JavaScript.

Basically, what is happening, is that I have a div with blue background, and my css applies a "cut" on it, slicing it diagonally. When the page first loads (or when CTRL+SHIFT+R), the "cut" is not there for a very short but noticeable duration, and then appears after the JavaScript loads.

I have this CSS

```css
.banner-bottom-fx 
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 0 solid transparent; /* changes via JavaScript */
    border-right: 0 solid white; /* changes via JavaScript */
}
```

Where border-top and border-right values change via this JavaScript

```js
function UpdateBannerFx()
{
    const banner = document.querySelector('.banner-bottom-fx');

    const borderRightWidth = window.innerWidth;
    const borderTopWidth = borderRightWidth / 30;

    banner.style.borderRightWidth = borderRightWidth + 'px';
    banner.style.borderTopWidth = borderTopWidth + 'px';
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() 
{
    UpdateBannerFx();
    // Update border widths when window is resized
    window.addEventListener('resize', UpdateBannerFx);
});
```

I know the "flicker" is due to my CSS styles.css, which loads in my header, and then the JavaScript which loads from main.js in the footer. Is there any way to prevent said flicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript for this. `100vw` is equivalent to `window.innerWidth`.

```css
.banner-bottom-fx {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: calc(100vw / 30) solid transparent; /* window.innerWidth / 30 */
    border-right: 100vw solid white;  /* window.innerWidth */
}
```

See [CSS Values and Units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units)

Comment: Instead of `3.33vw` couldn't you also use `calc(100vw / 3)` ? The result should be the same, but writing it this way might be clearer on the intent if someone checked the code.

Comment: @cloned Good point, thanks for the suggestion. I've changed my answer for better clarity

Comment: This was wonderful, thank you for the solution and link!